# Klondike Solitaire - impossible deck

Tags: solitaire-online

While playing solitaire in the Google Chrome browser, I do get only about 50% of the games finished. I never thought much of it, I just lost and took a new game. But I just finished a game except for two hidden cards. It could not be solved, but it appeared that some cards were missing!

[image]

It is a Klondike single deal game. The card in the deck is just the jack of diamonds, that's the only card I got left. There are two hidden cards, but I can see 10 cards missing:

2 club,
5 heart,
5 spade, 6 spade, 9 spade, 10 spade, queen spade,
3 diamond, 7 diamond, queen diamond

I've noticed mainly graphical glitches in the game when undoing previous moves, but I didn't use that feature here.

How come these are missing? It feels like I make a stupid thought mistake, but I can't spot it. Where are my missing cards?

Comment: Sounds like the game is just full of bugs.

Comment: What edition of the game is this specifically?  I can't find the one you're talking about.  Can you provide a link?

Comment: Yes, it is called `Solitaire online` and can be found in the chrome web store: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blpebaehgfgkcmmjjknibibbjacnplim

Comment: Going to agree with @Wipqozn. You're missing nothing. The game must be bugged. There are only 44 cards available in total when there should be 52.

Comment: "Unfortunately", my attempt at reproducing this was unsuccessful. Nevertheless, I am compelled to agree that it is a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To just put an answer here, assuming that the jack on the waste is indeed the last card in the stock, it's a bug.

Klondike Solitaire is played with one full deck of cards consisting of 52 cards, A to K of 4 suits. In that screenshot above, you have 11 cards on the Foundations, 1 card in the Waste, and 32 cards on the tableau, which totals to 44 cards.